# Checking if string contains a word that is subset of a word in a list

Tags: python

I want to extract `bananas-10` from `thought1` and `10-bananas` from `thought2`. How would I do this? I am stumped because I'm not sure how to figure out which item in foods was found in the string.

```
foods = ["bagels", "oranges", "bananas"]
thought1 = "I want some bananas-10"
thought2 = "I want some 10-bananas"
if any(food in thought1 for food in foods):
    # extractedfood = ???
```

Comment: Your question title and what you have described as what you want is completely different. You are asking to match if a word _contains_ a certain string, and then return that word; but your title is asking to look for the "word before or after it"; can you clarify what you need exactly?

Comment: Sorry I meant character before or after -- updated the title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this list comoprenhension approach:

```
text = thought1 + " " + thought2 # To handle both strings
result = [a for a in text.split() for b in foods if b in a]

print result
```

**Output:**

```
['bananas-10', '10-bananas']
```